# Почему wav файл не корректный?

Tags: python, python-3.x, аудио, wav

У меня есть sound.dat файл (очевидно, что в нем собраны все звуки, из игры Watch_Dogs 2). Я его открыл с помощью python3

```
>>> k[:300]
b'RIFFK9=\x00WAVEfmt B\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x02\x00\x80\xbb\x00\x00\xa3:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\xc4\xc3\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x00\xf58=\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd9\x00\x00\x00\xcb\x01\xc0\x02\xd0>\x00\x00\xb0@\x00\x00\x18\xcbi\xec\x08\x0bdata\xf58=\x00\xd7\x00)&\x9c\x80B\n*\xac\xc0B\x0b.\xbc\x00C\x0c>\xfc\x00D\x10B\x0cAD\x11F\x1c\x81D\x12J,\xc1\x84k\xa1\x896\x1ai\xa5\x99v\x1aj\xa9\xa9\xb6\x1ak\xad\x81\x16\x10\x08\x99@\xa0\x00\n\x0cd\x00\xc0\x01B\x82\x14\x00PX`\xe8\x10!\x02\xc4(00..-\x82\x10\x99!\x12\x11\x8bAbB5PTL\x07\x00\x8b\x0b\x0c\xf9\x00\x90\xa1\xb1\x91vq\x01]\x06\xb8\xa0\x8b\xbb\x0e\x84\x10\x84 \x04\xb18\x80\x02\x12pp\xc2\rO\xbc\xe1\t78A\xa7\xa8\xd4\x81\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\xc9\x06\x10\x11\x11\xcd\x1cG\x87\xc7\x07H\x88\xc8\x08I\x89\xc9\t\x8a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x1f\x00\x00I\n\x10\x11\x11\xcd\x1cG\x87\xc7\x07H\x88\xc8\x08I\x89\xc9\tJ \x80'
```

Я сразу же понял, что это wav файл.
Поэтому,

```
open('test.wav','wb').write(k[:400])
```

Но воспроизвести не получилось, неправильный формат. В чем ошибка?

```
user@user:~/path$ file sound.dat
sound.dat: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, stereo 48000 Hz
```

[image: Может, кому-то так будет удобнее]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно посмотреть на заголовок; описаний его довольно много. Вот навскидку [одно](http://microsin.net/programming/PC/wav-format.html), [другое](https://audiocoding.ru/article/2008/05/22/wav-file-structure.html), [третье](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/)

По буквам выйдет так:

```
52 49 46 46    RIFF, идентификатор куска
4B 39 3D 00    = 4012363 байт, длина куска
57 41 56 45    WAVE, идентификатор куска
66 6D 74 20    fmt , подтип формата
42 00 00 00    = 66 байт, длина описания формата
FF FF          = -1, кастомный кодек
```

Тут уже можно остановиться - кодек проприетарный, данные недекодируемы.

Comment: т.е. кодек свой написан?

Comment: Да. Возможно и то, что кодек стандартный, но разработчики специально поставили такой код формата, чтобы ресурсы не разбирали :)

Comment: еще заметил, что раздел 'data' начинается с 86 байта, а не с 44

Comment: Да, поле формата длиннее, чем для стандартного PCM. В таких заголовках лучше их разбирать и смотреть в длинах полей и смещениях, где по-настоящему начинаются данные

Comment: А еще попытался, взять начальных 44 байта у нормального файла wav + с 86 до конца у sound.dat = test_3.wav . Но ничего не получилось. Монотонный шум